# Converting the Inline Json Data to Remote Json File

Tags: json, yui3, yui-datatable, yui-datasource

I used the answer at : [YUI 3 -Datatable with Paginator + Query Builder + Sort tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481461/yui-3-datatable-with-paginator-query-builder-sort)

to for the samples http://jsbin.com/iwijek/10 and http://jsfiddle.net/UwjUt/ which have inline json data.  I wanted to parse the remote json file for which I used the .get() as per YUI 3 docs. But bit does not do anything. plz check these examples and help me in parsing the remote json file.

```
{       var url = "file:///e:/Documents/json-search.txt";
    var modelList;
    dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({ source: url });
        // comment

        // var modelList = new Y.ModelList();

        modelList = new Y.ModelList.Get({
        source: url   });

        modelList.add();

}
```

json-search.txt

```
[{
        name : 'Joe Bloggs',
        company : 'ABC Inc',
        state : 'AZ',
        cost : 100
        },
        {
        name : 'Jane Mary',
        company : 'Bits and Bobs Ltd',
        state : 'TX',
        cost : 1000
        },
        {
        name : 'Paul Smith',
        company : 'PS Clothing PLC',
        state : 'TX',
        cost :400
        },
        {
        name : 'Jack Jones',
        company : 'jackjones.com',
        State : 'NY',
        cost: 9999
        },
        {
        name : 'Crazy Horse',
        company : 'Wacky Places Ltd.',
        state : 'MI',
        cost : 632
        }]
```

I also tried to pass the datasource to the ModelList

```
    YUI.add(

    'datatable-filter',

    function(Y) { 

    /**
       Adds support for filtering the table data by API methods

       @module datatable
       @submodule datatable-filter
       @since 3.5.0
    **/
    var YLang = Y.Lang,
    isBoolean = YLang.isBoolean,
    isString = YLang.isString,
    isArray = YLang.isArray,
    isObject = YLang.isObject,

    toArray = Y.Array,
    sub = YLang.sub;

    /**
       <pre><code>
       var table = new Y.DataTable({
       columns: [ 'id', 'username', 'name', 'birthdate' ],
       data: [ ... ],
       filters: true // this will render a filter input box for every column
       });

       table.render('#table');
       </code></pre>

       Setting `filters` to `true` will enable UI filtering for all columns. To enable
       UI filtering for certain columns only, set `filters` to an array of column keys,
       or just add `filters: true` to the respective column configuration objects.
       This uses the default setting of `filters: auto` for the DataTable instance.

       <pre><code>
       var table = new Y.DataTable({
       columns: [
       'id',
       { key: 'username', renderFilter: true },
       { key: 'name' },
       { key: 'birthdate', renderFilter: true, filter : "=123", filterFn : customFilterFn }
       ],
       data: [ ... ]
       // filters: 'auto' is the default
       });

       To disable UI filtering for all columns, set `filters` to `false`. This still
       permits filtering via the API methods.

       filter via api:

       var filterBy = 
       {  
       username : "=student",
       name       : "%richard",
       birthdate  : ">01-01-1975"
       }

    table.set("filterBy",filterBy);

    As new records are inserted into the table's `data` ModelList, they will be checked against the filter to determine if they will be rendered

    The current filters are stored in the `filterBy` attribute. Assigning this value at instantiation will automatically filter your data.

    Filtering is done by a simple value comparison using '=', '!=', '<', '<=', '>', '>='  on the field value. 

    If you need custom filtering, add a filter function in the column's `filterFn` property. // TODO...

    <pre><code>
    function applePiesFilter(a) {
    return a.get("type") == 'apple' ? true : false;
    }

    var table = new Y.DataTable({
    columns: [ 'id', 'username', { key: name, filterFn: nameFilter }, 'birthdate' ],
    data: [ ... ],
    filters: [ 'username', 'name', 'birthdate' ]
    });
    </code></pre>

    See the user guide for more details.

    @class DataTable.Filters
    @for DataTable
    @since 3.5.0
    **/
    function Filters() {}

    Filters.ATTRS = {

        // Which columns in the UI should suggest and respond to filtering interaction
        // pass an empty array if no UI columns should show filters, but you want the
        // table.filter(...) API

        /**
           Controls which columns can show a filtering input

           Acceptable values are:

           * "auto" - (default) looks for `renderFilter: true` in the column configurations
           * "true" - all columns have a filter field rendered
           * "false" - no UI filters are enabled
           * {String[]} - array of key names to give filter fields

           @attribute filters
           @type {String|String[]|Boolean}
           @default "auto"
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        filters: {
        value: 'auto',
        validator: '_validateFilters'
        },

        /**
           The current filter configuration to maintain in the data.

           Accepts column `key` objects with a single property the value of the filter
           E.g. `{ username: '%student' }`
           E.g. `[{ username : '%student' }, { age : '<40'}]

           @attribute filterBy
           @type {String|String[]|Object|Object[]}
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        filterBy: {
        validator: '_validateFilterBy'
        },

        /**
           Strings containing language for filtering tooltips.

           @attribute strings
           @type {Object}
           @default (strings for current lang configured in the YUI instance config)
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        strings: {}
    };

    Y.mix(Filters.prototype, {

        /**
           Filter the data in the `data` ModelList and refresh the table with the new
           order.

           @method filter
           @param {String|String[]|Object|Object[]} fields The field(s) to filter by
           @param {Object} [payload] Extra `filter` event payload you want to send along
           @return {DataTable}
           @chainable
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        filter : function (fields, payload) {

        /**
           Notifies of an impending filter, either from changing the filter in the UI
           header, or from a call to the `filter`  method.

           The requested filter is available in the `filterBy` property of the event.

           The default behavior of this event sets the table's `filterBy` attribute.

           @event filter
           @param {String|String[]|Object|Object[]} filterBy The requested filter
           @preventable _defFilterFn
        **/
        return this.fire('filter', Y.merge((payload || {}), {
            filterBy: fields || this.get('filterBy')
        }));
        },

        /**
           Template for the row that will hold the filter inputs
           @property FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE
           @type {HTML}
           @value 
        **/

        FILTERS_HEADER_ROW_TEMPLATE : '<tr class="{filterRowClassName}" tabindex="0"></tr>',

        /**
           Template for the row that will hold the filter inputs
           @property FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE
           @type {HTML}
           @value 
           //<select><option value="=">=</option><option value="%">%</option><option value="!=">!=</option><option value="!%">!%</option><option value="&gt;">%gt</option><option value="&gt;=">&gt;=</option><option value="&lt;">&lt;</option><option value="&lt;=">&lt;=</option></select>
           **/

        FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE : '<th class="{className}" tabindex="0"  rowspan="1" colspan="1" title="Filter by {colName}">' + 
        '<div class="{linerClass}" tabindex="0"><input type="text" data-yui3-col-key="{colKey}" class="{inputClass}"/></div></th>',

        /**
           Template for the row that will doesn't have filter inputs
           @property FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE_NONE
           @type {HTML}
           @value 
        **/

        FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE_NONE : '<th class="{className}" tabindex="0"  rowspan="1" colspan="1" title="Filtering unavailable on this field"></th>',

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Protected properties and methods
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
           Filters the `data` ModelList based on the new `filterBy` configuration.

           @method _afterFilterByChange
           @param {EventFacade} e The `filterByChange` event
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _afterFilterByChange: function (e) {

        var filters;

        // Can't use a setter because it's a chicken and egg problem. The
        // columns need to be set up to translate, but columns are initialized
        // from Core's initializer. So construction-time assignment would
        // fail.
        // WHAT DOES THIS MEAN??

        this._setFilterBy();

        if (this._filterBy.length) {

            // build the filter function
            this._buildFilterFn();

            // get the filtered data
            this._filteredData = this.data.filter( { asList : true }, this._filterFn);

        } else {
            this._filteredData = this.data;
        }
        // 'hide' the filtered rows
        this._hideFilteredData();

        },

        /**
           @description if the row is not in the filtered data hide it, otherwise show it
           @method _hideFilteredData
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _hideFilteredData: function () {

        var i,len,clientId;

        for(i=0, len = this.data.size();  this._filteredData.getById && i < len; ++i) {

            clientId = this.data.item(i).get("clientId");

            if(this._filteredData.getByClientId(clientId)) {

            this.get("contentBox").one("tbody").one("[data-yui3-record=" + clientId + "]").setStyle("display","table-row");

            } else {

            this.get("contentBox").one("tbody").one("[data-yui3-record=" + clientId + "]").setStyle("display","none");
            }
        }
        },

        /**
           Applies the filtering logic to the new ModelList if the `newVal` is a new
           ModelList.

           @method _afterFilterDataChange
           @param {EventFacade} e the `dataChange` event
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _afterFilterDataChange: function (e) {
        // object values always trigger a change event, but we only want to
        // call _initFilterFn if the value passed to the `data` attribute was a
        // new ModelList, not a set of new data as an array, or even the same
        // ModelList.
        if (e.prevVal !== e.newVal || e.newVal.hasOwnProperty('_compare')) {
            //          this._initFilterFn();
        }
        },

        /**
           Checks if any of the fields in the modified record are fields that are
           currently being filtered by, and if so, refilters the `data` ModelList.

           @method _afterFilterRecordChange
           @param {EventFacade} e The Model's `change` event
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _afterFilterRecordChange: function (e) {
        var i, len;

        for (i = 0, len = this._filterBy.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (e.changed[this._filterBy[i].key]) {
            this.data.filter();
            break;
            }
        }
        },

        /**
           Subscribes to state changes that warrant updating the UI, and adds the
           click handler for triggering the filter operation from the UI.

           @method _bindFilterUI
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _bindFilterUI: function () {

        var handles = this._eventHandles;

        //  'filterByChange' -> need to update UI 

        if (!handles.filterAttrs) {
            handles.filterAttrs = this.after(
            ['filtersChange', 'columnsChange'],
            Y.bind('_uiSetFilters', this));
        }

        if (!handles.filterUITrigger && this._theadNode) {
            handles.filterUITrigger = this.delegate(['keyup','blur'],
                                Y.rbind('_onUITriggerFilter', this),
                                '.' + this.getClassName('filter', 'input'));
        }
        },

        /**
           Sets the `filterBy` attribute from the `filter` event's `e.filterBy` value.

           @method _defFilterFn
           @param {EventFacade} e The `filter` event
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _defFilterFn: function (e) {
        this.set.apply(this, ['filterBy', e.filterBy].concat(e.details));
        },

        /**
           Sets up the initial filter state and instance properties. Publishes events
           and subscribes to attribute change events to maintain internal state.

           @method initializer
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        initializer: function () {

        var boundParseFilter = Y.bind('_parseFilter', this);

        this._parseFilter();
        this._setFilterBy();

        this._initFilterStrings();

        //          dataChange : Y.bind('_afterFilterDataChange', this),        
        //      
        //      filterChange : boundParseFilter


        this.after({
            'sort' :  this._hideFilteredData,
            'columnsChange' : boundParseFilter,
            'filterByChange' : Y.bind('_afterFilterByChange', this),
            'table:renderHeader': Y.bind('_renderFilters', this)});


        //      this.data.after(this.data.model.NAME + ":change",
        //              Y.bind('_afterFilterRecordChange', this));

        // TODO: this event needs magic, allowing async remote filtering
//      this.publish('filter', {
//          defaultFn: Y.bind('_defFilterFn', this)
//      });
        },

        /**
           Add the filter related strings to the `strings` map.
           @method _initFilterStrings
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _initFilterStrings: function () {
        // Not a valueFn because other class extensions will want to add to it
        this.set('strings', Y.mix((this.get('strings') || {}),
                      Y.Intl.get('datatable-filter')));
        },

        /**
           @description Fires the `filter` event in response to user changing the UI filters
           @method _onUITriggerFilter
           @param {DOMEventFacade} e The `mouseout` event
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _onUITriggerFilter: function (e) {

        var colKey = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-yui3-col-key'),
        column = colKey && this.getColumn(colKey),
        filterBy = this.get("filterBy") || {},
        i, len;

        e.halt(); // not doing anything anyway?

        if (column) {
            filterBy[colKey] = e.currentTarget.get("value");
        }

        this.set("filterBy",filterBy);

        },

        /**
           @description Build the filter function from the column config, this function is passed to the model list fiter() method
           @method _buildFilterFn
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _buildFilterFn: function () {

        var i,len,op1,op2, key, filter, filterFn;

        filterFn = function(model,index,modelList) {

            var key,filter,op1,op2,val,filter,passesFilter = true;

            for(i=0,len = this._filterBy.length; i< len && passesFilter; ++i) {

            key = this._filterBy[i].key;
            filter = this._filterBy[i].filter;

            val = model.get(key) || '';

            op1 = filter.substr(0,1);
            op2 = filter.substr(1,1);

            if(op2 == '=') {
                switch(op1) {
                case '!':
                // not equal
                if(val.toLowerCase() == filter.substr(2).toLowerCase()) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

                case '>':
                // greater or equal
                if(parseInt(val) < parseInt(filter.substr(2))) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;              

                case '<':
                // less than or equal
                if(parseInt(val) > parseInt(filter.substr(2))) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;
                }

            } else if (op2 == '%' && op1 =='!') {

                // not like
                if((val.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.substr(2).toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
                passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

            } else {
                switch(op1) {
                case '=':
                // equal
                if(val.toLowerCase() != filter.substr(1).toLowerCase()) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

                case '>':
                // greater than
                if(parseInt(val) <= parseInt(filter.substr(1))) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

                case '<':
                // less than
                if(parseInt(val) >= parseInt(filter.substr(1))) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

                case '%':
                // like
                if((val.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.substr(1).toLowerCase()) === -1)) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;

                default:
                // consider to be like
                if((String(val).toLowerCase().indexOf(String(filter).toLowerCase()) === -1)) {
                    passesFilter = false;
                }
                break;
                }
            }
            }
            return passesFilter;
        };

        this._filterFn = Y.bind(filterFn,this);

        },

        /**
           @description Normalizes the possible input values for the `filter` attribute setting up the column config as appropriate
           @method _parseFilter
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _parseFilter: function () {

        var filters = this.get('filters'),

        columns = [],
        i, len, col;

        col = this._displayColumns.slice();

        this._uiFilters = false;

        if(filters === 'auto') {

            // look for key on columns
            col = this._displayColumns.slice();

            for(i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            if(col[i].renderFilter) {
                this._uiFilters = true;
            }
            }
        } else if(filters === true) {

            // provide UI filters for all cols
            col = this._displayColumns.slice();

            for(i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            this._uiFilters = true;
            this._displayColumns[i].renderFilter = true;
            }
        } else if (isArray(filters)) {

            // provide UI filters on the specified cols (plural)
            for (i = 0, len=filters.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if(col = this.getColumn(filters[i])) {
                this._uiFilters = true;
                col.renderFilter = true;
            }
            }

        } else if (filters) {

            // provide UI filter on the specifed 'COL' (singular)
            for (i = 0, len = col.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (col[i].key === filters) {
                this._uiFilters = true;
                this._displayColumns[i].renderFilter = true;
                i = len;
            }
            }
        }
        },

        /**
           Initial application of the filters UI.

           @method _renderFilters
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _renderFilters: function () {

        this._uiSetFilters();
        this._bindFilterUI();
        },

        /**
           @description Parses the current `filterBy` attribute and updates the columns
           @method _setFilterBy
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _setFilterBy: function () {

        var columns = this._displayColumns,
        filterBy = this.get('filterBy') || {},
        filteredClass = ' ' + this.getClassName('filtered'),
        i, len, name, dir, field, column;

        this._filterBy = [];

        // Purge current filter state from column configs
        for (i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len; ++i) {

            column = columns[i];            
            delete columns[i].filter;

            if (column.className) {
            // TODO: be more thorough
            column.className = column.className.replace(filteredClass, '');
            }
        }

        for (key in filterBy) {

            if(filterBy[key]!='') {

            // Allow filtering of any model field and any column
            column = this.getColumn(key) || { _id: key, key: key };

            if (column) {

                column.filter = filterBy[key];

                if (!column.className) {
                column.className = '';
                }

                column.className += filteredClass;

                this._filterBy.push(column);
            }
            } 
        }
        },

        /**
           Array of column configuration objects of those columns that need UI setup
           for user interaction.

           @property _filters
           @type {Object[]}
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        //_filters: null,

        /**
           Array of column configuration objects for those columns that are currently
           being used to filter the data. Fake column objects are used for fields that
           are not rendered as columns.

           @property _filterBy
           @type {Object[]}
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        //_filterBy: null,

        /**
           Replacement `comparator` for the `data` ModelList that defers filtering logic
           to the `_compare` method. The deferral is accomplished by returning `this`.

           @method _filterComparator
           @param {Model} item The record being evaluated for filter position
           @return {Model} The record
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _filterComparator: function (item) {
        // Defer filtering to ModelList's _compare
        return item;
        },

        /**
           Applies the appropriate classes to the `boundingBox` and column headers to
           indicate filter state and filterability.

           Also currently wraps the header content of filters columns in a `<div>`
           liner to give a CSS anchor for filter indicators.

           @method _uiSetFilters
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _uiSetFilters: function () {

        var columns = this._displayColumns.slice(),
        filtersClass = this.getClassName('filters', 'column'),
        filtersHidden = this.getClassName("filters","hidden"),
        filterRowClass = this.getClassName("filters","row"),
        filteredClass = this.getClassName('filtered'),
        linerClass = this.getClassName('filter', 'liner'),
        i, len, col, node, liner, title, desc;

        this.get('boundingBox').toggleClass(
            this.getClassName('filters'),
            columns.length);


        /// NEED TO ADDRESS
        if((node = this._theadNode.one("." + filterRowClass))) {
            node.remove(true);
        }

        if(columns.length>0 && this._uiFilters) {
            tr = this._theadNode.appendChild(Y.Lang.sub(
            this.FILTERS_HEADER_ROW_TEMPLATE, {
                filterRowClassName: filterRowClass }));

            for (i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len; ++i) {

            if(columns[i].renderFilter) {
                tr.append(Y.Lang.sub(
                this.FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE, {
                    className: this.getClassName("filter","cell"),
                    colKey : columns[i].key,
                    colName : columns[i].label || columns[i].key,
                    inputClass : this.getClassName("filter","input"),
                    linerClass: linerClass
                }));
            } else {
                tr.append(Y.Lang.sub(
                this.FILTERS_HEADER_CELL_TEMPLATE_NONE, {
                    className: this.getClassName("no-filter")
                }));
            }
            }
        } 
        },

        /**
           Allows values `true`, `false`, "auto", or arrays of column names through.

           @method _validateFilters
           @param {Any} val The input value to `set("filters", VAL)`
           @return {Boolean}
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _validateFilters: function (val) {
        return val === 'auto' || isBoolean(val) || isArray(val);
        },

        /**
           Allows strings, arrays of strings, objects, or arrays of objects.

           @method _validateFilterBy
           @param {String|String[]|Object|Object[]} val The new `filterBy` value
           @return {Boolean}
           @protected
           @since 3.5.0
        **/
        _validateFilterBy: function (val) {
        return val;
        return val === null ||
            isString(val) ||
            isObject(val, true) ||
            (isArray(val) && (isString(val[0]) || isObject(val, true)));
        }

    }, true);

    Y.DataTable.Filters = Filters;

    Y.Base.mix(Y.DataTable, [Filters]);
    },"0.1", {
    requires : []});



    YUI().use('datatable-sort','datatable-filter',function(Y) {
                    // comment
                    //var modelList = new Y.ModelList();


       var url = "file:///e:/Documents/json-search.txt";
    var modelList, datasource;

    modelList = new Y.ModelList();
    datasource = Y.DataSource.IO({ source: "file:///e:/Documents/json-search.txt" });



     modelList.plug(Y.Plugin.ModelListDataSource, {
    source : datasource,   });

    datasource.sendRequest();


                var dataTable = new Y.DataTable (
            {
                            columns : [ {key:"name",label:"Person",renderFilter:true,filter:"Joe"},"company",{key:"state",renderFilter:true},{key:"cost",renderFilter:true}],
                        data : modelList, sortable : true,          filters : 'auto'
            }).render("#table");    

                modelList.item(1).set("id",102);
        Y.one("#showhidefilters").on("click",function(e) {e.halt();Y.one("#table").one(".yui3-datatable-filters-row").toggleClass("yui3-datatable-filters-hidden");});
        });
```